# python regex match all

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a 4-line multi-line match.  My code finds the first one.  But not the others.

Here is the pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile("([a-z]+\.com\.|net\.)[.\s\S]+(Z[A-Z0-9]+)")
```

Here is the subject:

```
sub = """yahoo.com.
Public
8
Z2RVE9XGX4PFJN
google.com.
Public
7
Z2VATLWTLBDR5D
"""
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("([a-z]+\.com\.|net\.)[.\s\S]+(Z[A-Z0-9]+)")

sub = """yahoo.com.
Public
8
Z2RVE9JJGX4PFJN
google.com.
Public
7
Z2VATZOPLBDR5D
"""

m = pattern.findall(sub)

print(m)
```

Here is the result:

```
[('yahoo.com.', 'Z2RVE9JJGX4PFJN')]
```

And finally, here is the desired result:

```
[('yahoo.com.', 'Z2RVE9JJGX4PFJN'), ('google.com', Z2VATZOPLBDR5D')]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Just make your match less greedy:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("([a-z]+\.com\.|net\.)[\s\S]+?(Z[A-Z0-9]+)")
# Note the 'less greedy' addition                 ^
# The '.' is not necessary in the           ^ in the character class
sub = """yahoo.com.
Public
8
Z2RVE9JJGX4PFJN
google.com.
Public
7
Z2VATZOPLBDR5D
"""

m = pattern.findall(sub)

print(m)
```

Prints:

```
[('yahoo.com.', 'Z2RVE9JJGX4PFJN'), ('google.com.', 'Z2VATZOPLBDR5D')]
```

For greater specificity on the ends of your patterns, you may want to use anchors:

```
pattern = re.compile("^([a-z]+\.com\.|net\.)$[\s\S]+?^(Z[A-Z0-9]+)$", re.M)
# Start of line       ^                              ^ 
# End of line                               ^                     ^
# Multi line flag                                                       ^
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly.  I'd mark it correct if I knew how.

Comment: I went back and studied a bit. As a side note, I'd like to point out where I think I went wrong for others who have mediocre regex skills. Here "[.\s\S]".  I believe that "." was an import part of the problem, in that it matched everything in a greedy fashion until the last (Z[A-Z0-9]+).  Thanks again, Dawg.

Comment: The portion `[\s\S]` matches any character including `\n`. It will run right over the next match. Rarely used without `?` unless you want to run all the way to the end of something.

Comment: Aww I see.  Thanks so much for the education.